# Index dynamic input to others dynamic input array

Tags: javascript, php

I have a form with dynamically created input like this (simplified):
I can create more people with ADD PERSON button.
For each person i can add more hobbies.

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".add_person").click(function(){
    var new_fieldset = $(".person:first").clone();
    $(".person:last").after(new_fieldset);
  });

  $(".add_hobby").click(function(){
    var new_input = '<input type="text" name="hobby[]" />';
    $("this").closest("fieldset").find("div_hobbies").append(new_input);
  });

});
```

php:

```
<fieldset class="person">
<input name="name[]" value="">
<div class="div_hobbies"></div>
<a class="add_hobby">ADD HOBBY</a>
</fieldset>

<a class="add_person">ADD PERSON</a>
```

I'd like to post result with method POST and retrieve an array but i don't know how to index hobbies with a correct person (some person can have 0 hobbies):

Example i want:

```
John with hobbies "FISHING", "DIVING"
Carl with no hobbies
Eddy with hobby "SINGING"
Paul with hobbies "RUNNING", "DIVING", "CYCLING"
```

var_dump($_POST["name"])

```
array(4) {
[0] => string "John",
[1] => string "Carl",
[2] => string "Eddy",
[3] => string "Paul)
}
```

But with var_dump($_POST['hobby']) i get a single array like this:

```
    array(6) {
        [0] => string "FISHING",
        [1] => string "DIVING",
        [2] => string "SINGING",
        [3] => string "RUNNING",
        [4] => string "DIVING",
        [5] => string "CYCLING"
        }
```

How can I index hobbies with correct person?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is achievable by adding a little more javascript to your code. The solution is to make your hobby input field name a two-dimensional array.

```
<input type="text" name="hobby[][]" />
```

When you submit the form, use javascript logic to loop through the elements and make the first index of hobby[][] as the person name. For example, after applying JS logic, the form elements should be,

```
<input type="text" name="hobby[jack][]" />
<input type="text" name="hobby[jack][]" />
<input type="text" name="hobby[rose][]" />
<input type="text" name="hobby[rose][]" />
```

Now submit the form and in the PHP page, you will get this as a two-dimensional array where the first level key is the person name and their hobbies inside.